# PHP - Acquire data which is loaded into DOM via Javascript AFTER page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to AJAX and PHP. I am trying to fetch the "In total" value on this page
http://csgobackpack.net/?nick=xreptar2
by loading its html via a PHP HTML Dom Parser and obtaining the value from its container.

However, I am encountering two issues.

1. The parser does not load the page at "?nick=xreptar2" and loads "http://csgobackpack.net/" instead
2. The "In total" numerical value is loaded into DOM via Javascript after page load and I cannot fetch it

How do I go about this? I am using this parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

My code:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://csgobackpack.net/?nick=xreptar2");

echo $html->plaintext;

echo ________________;

foreach($html->find('p') as $element) {
       echo $element->plaintext;
}
?>
```

Online php: http://watchgameofthron.es/ajax/stackoverflow1.php

The above online preview shows that no HTML is being parsed. I therefore edited the code to make it parse from another webpage with similar functionality.

```
  <?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://steam.tools/itemvalue/#/xreptar2-730");

echo $html->plaintext;

echo ________________;

foreach($html->find('p') as $element) {
       echo $element->plaintext;
}
?>
```

Online php: http://watchgameofthron.es/ajax/stackoverflow2.php

Comment: We need to see some code you're using. Please paste it in your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask. HINT: Add code here since links go stale. Also you are loading multiple jQueries at your site

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "fetch". Do you mean, "make a request to the server" or just "obtain"?

Comment: Included the code. The site is not mine.
By fetch I mean obtain, yes.
Also included a live preview (stackoverflow1.php). For some reason, it is not parsing any html..

I created a new php (stackoverflow2.php) which attempts to parse from another source since the original wasn't fetching anything from the site.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look into the parsers documentation, i'm fairly sure it's only loading the initial DOM elements, and doesn't run any scripts.

If you wannt to get the value of your backpack, you should use the sites API:

http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetInventoryValue/?id=xreptar2&ref=1

Its a simple GET request, which then returns a simple JSON string which you can convert to an object via `json_decode`.

You don't need to use any fancy external modules to do this.

It should be as simple as this:

```
$profileID = "xreptar2";
$connection = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($connection, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetInventoryValue/?id={$profileID}&ref=1",
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true
]);

$jsonString = curl_exec($connection);

if ( $jsonString !== false )
{
    $data = json_decode($jsonString);
}
```

Then you can use the `$data` which according to the API will be in the following format:
{"success":true,"value":"16965.24","items":"734","currency":"USD"}

I hope it helps

Comment: How did you find this API? Also, the API has a limit of 30 requests per hour. Is there a way how I can bypass this limit or avoid the API altogether?

Comment: Also, thanks to your answer I think I have found another way to approach this.
Run the HTML parser on http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetInventoryValue/?id=xreptar2&ref=1
and then explode the plaintext.

Comment: I also tried the code you gave me but $data is empty.

Comment: I found the API link on the bottom of the page you linked, but here is the link: [API](http://csgobackpack.net/api/). Also if you can retrieve the the contents, then you should just use `json_parse` on the returned data; from then you can use it as an object (stdClass). I admit the `curl` method i've provided isn't tested, but i just wanted to give you a general idea. I suggest you read the full API description, and continue from there :)